# Navigate command

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, incompatibility

I have a page which unfortunately uses the old JavaScript command "navigate" (used to redirect to another page) instead of the currently used "location". There is unfortunately no way for me to change the code so I'm left with having to use IE, which is a problem for example on my PC at home, where I have Linux.

Browsers like Chrome or FF refuse to execute this and show "navigate not defined" in the console. Just out of curiosity, can anyone think of any way how to overcome this? Maybe some extension or possibility to teach the browser custom commands? I tried searching for this but didnt find anything. But before I completely resign I thought I would ask here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: *There is unfortunately no way for me to change the code* - There's your answer right there. Unfortunately, no.

Comment: In the end i installed a plugin which injects custom js to every page and created a navigate function with location command inside it. Works like a charm